# PHP AWS SNS SDK - Badge

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Simple question, how to send badge number in push notifications, using AWS SNS ?

I found out that it has to be formatted in the json format somehow, but not sure how to do it.

AWS docs don't have that info, or at least I didn't found it.

Thanks!

My code so far, which works:

```
    $sns = SnsClient::factory(array(
        'key' => $this->app()->getConfig()->get('aws.sns.key'),
        'secret' => $this->app()->getConfig()->get('aws.sns.secret'),
        'region' => $this->app()->getConfig()->get('aws.sns.region'),
    ));

    $payload = [
        'Message' => $this->_message,
        'TargetArn' => $this->_device->getDeviceArn()
    ];

    $sns->publish($payload);
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as the answer.  If not, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, take a look at this AWS Developer Forum 
[article](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=480037)

To sum that article up, in your example, _message needs to look something like this:

```
{"APNS":"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"<message>\"}}"}
```

and you need to add

```
'MessageStructure' => 'json',
```

to `$payload`

This is the code I use for building the message JSON:

```
    $contents = array(); 
    $contents['badge'] = "1"; 
    $contents['alert'] = addslashes($push_message); 
    $contents['sound'] = "default"; 
    $push = array("aps" => $contents); 
    $push_json = json_encode($push);

    $json = json_encode(array('APNS' => $push_json));

    $sns->publish(array('MessageStructure' => 'json',
            'Message' => $json,
            'TargetArn' => $endpointArn));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey moebius, I'm Pavan, and I'm trying to send a basic push notification via my php application to my iOS device. I have laravel installed and using the AWS sdk. I have gotten to the point of succesfully creating the snsClient but I am trying to now figure out how to create endpointarns on the fly in php using th aws sdk. Can you provide me some help? maybe a Q & A sessions? or will you email me? kataria.pavan@gmail.com perhaps even a quick skype session as I would like your help Moebius! Thank you.
Pavan

Comment: @Pavan You should find everything you need online.

Comment: @moebus. Yep, you're right. If anyone is struggling to send push notifications via SNS and in need of some help, feel free to message me.  I've been able to have a lovely push notification system going, these push notifications are sent based on a scheduler linked to a table. It's awesme.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to reset the badge number, you can publish to SNS endpoint with `{badge:0}`

```
{
    "APNS_SANDBOX":"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Removing the badge\", \"badge\":0}}"
}
```

Hope that helps someone.